# Create a typedef from an imported type

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

To configure my module, users have to export a function from a config file: like so

```js
export default (foo, bar, baz) => {}
```

As these are all complex types, to make things a bit simpler, I'd like to add types they can use with JSDoc.

Now, the following is fully functional, but it is a bit repetitive:

```js
/**
 * @param {import('module').Foo} foo
 * @param {import('module').Bar} bar
 * @param {import('module').Baz} baz 
 */
export default (foo, bar, baz) => {}
```

Ideally, what I'd like to do is simply create a typedef from `import('module')`, for example:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import('module')} Module
 *
 * @param {Module.Foo} foo
 * @param {Module.Bar} bar
 * @param {Module.Baz} baz
 */
export default (foo, bar, baz) => {}
```

While this does not seem to be functional, is there a method of getting this to work? The real function has 6 parameters, not 3, so `import('module')` is a bit ridiculous line after line.

Is there any way to get this behavior? I can edit the TS if need be, right now it's just plain `export type Foo...` and the like.

Comment: I am not very clear about your question.
However, I think using alias during import might solve your problem.
For a default export, you can use something like `import alias from 'module';`.
Then call those members using the alias you like.

Comment: @cindy50633 You need to use dynamic import in JSDoc. You cannot use imported types like that. As far as I am aware, you also cannot default export multiple types, so that wouldn't work anyways. You could of course do `import * as module from 'module'`, but that won't work with JSDoc so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good amount of time trying to figure this out. Many answers are TypeScript-specific. Here's what I found works in my commonJS app (without the need for importing/exporting modules).

- Create a .js file e.g. typedefs.js
- Use @exports on the typedef(s)
- (Optional) Put @namespace at the top of the file and @memberof in the typedef(s) if you want them separated out from out Type definitions
- Reference the typedef by name in another file
- NOTE: the typedefs.js file needs to be in the folder you're running jsdoc on -- although not necessarily at the same level

  - e.g. `jsdoc -r /project/folder` where 'folder' contains the typedefs.js file and the file(s) referencing the typedef

The typedefs.js file content:

```
/**
 * @namespace typedefs
 */

/**
 * @exports  myDef
 * @typedef  myDef
 * @type     {Object}
 * @property {string} aString
 * @property {Object} anObject
 * @memberof typedefs
 */
```

The typedef in use in another file (e.g. folder/file.js):

```
/**
 * I'm a function
 * @param   {Object}  state
 * @param   {myDef}   x
 * @returns {Object}  state
 */
const function = (state, x) => state;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Create a global module. **A global module is one that doesn't export anything** and just declares the types/values. Take the following example:

**types.js**

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{a: string}} Foo
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{b: string}} Bar
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{c: string}} Baz
 */
```

And then use the types as globals. It's going to be like the following:

```js
/**
 * @param {Foo} foo
 * @param {Bar} bar
 * @param {Baz} baz
 */
 export default (foo, bar, baz) => {}
```

[image]

### Solution 2

Just import the module as you normally do with `import` or `require` and use it as the module type.

```js
import * as Module from './b'

/**
 * @param {Module.Foo} foo
 * @param {Module.Bar} bar
 * @param {Module.Baz} baz
 */
export default (foo, bar, baz) => {}
```

[image]

or:

```js
const Module = require('./b')

/**
 * @param {Module.Foo} foo
 * @param {Module.Bar} bar
 * @param {Module.Baz} baz
 */
export default (foo, bar, baz) => {}
```

[image]

Comment: As the example clearly shows, there is no module being imported. There is no JS to the module to import even if one wanted to. It's only types.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that. Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the answer with another solution for this problem. Please take a look.

Comment: As I said, this is a module. Node modules cannot declare types that will get picked up on automatically. Users would need to alter their `tsconfig.json`, which is less likely to happen than a slightly verbose JSDoc comment.